# Python logging: create log if not exists or open and continue logging if it does

Tags: python, logging, filehandler, python-logging

I'm writing some code that uses the python `logging` system. The idea is that if the `LOG` doesn't already exist create the log but if it does then get the log and resume logging to that file. Here is my code:

```
import logging
import os

log_filename='Transactions.log')
if os.path.isfile(log_filename)!=True:
    LOG = logging.getLogger('log_filename')
    LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create file handler which logs even debug messages
    fh = logging.FileHandler('log_filename')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create console handler with a higher log level
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('-->%(asctime)s - %(name)s:%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handlers to the logger
    LOG.addHandler(fh)
    LOG.addHandler(ch)
else:
    LOG=logging.getLogger()
```

I suspect the problem is with my `else` block but I don't know how to fix. Could anybody shed some light on this situation.

Comment: set up your logger once and then import `LOG` from any place you want, no need to check if the log file exists

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The logging module's `FileHandler` takes care of that for you. No need for complexity.

The handler takes an optional `mode` parameter, to specify whether it starts writing or appending data to it.

From [the docs](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/logging.handlers#logging.FileHandler):

> **`class logging.FileHandler(filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False)`**
>
> The specified file is opened and used as the stream for logging. If
>   `mode` is not specified, `'a'` is used.

Comment: If the directory does not exist, you will still get an exception. Logging is happy to create a new file for you, but not a whole directory structure.

Comment: Which mode should @CiaranWelsh specify in order to create the file if not present?

Comment: @UserK if file is not present, either of `a` or `w` would be fine. `a` would append to the same file in next run, whereas `w` mode will delete the old file and create an entirely new one. Also read what @mightypile commented above.

Comment: On Python 2.7, it doesn't seem to work. `FileHandler` can't find the path and it returns error unless you explicitly make a path using `os.makedirs()`

Answer (score 37):

For anyone who was trying to create a new directory structure like `logs/mylogfile.log`, as @mightypile mentioned, FileHandler will not create a new directory structure for you. I used `os.makedirs` to ensure the directory structure.

```
import os
import logging

log_filename = "logs/output.log"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log_filename), exist_ok=True)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename, mode="w", encoding=None, delay=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe it's `log_filename` on the last line

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
LOG = logging.getLogger('log_filename')
```

for the first time a global variable is created.
Hence, you could also add the following code to the script above:

```
global LOG
if LOG is not None:
    print("found logger !")
else:
    ("no global variable logger found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use absolute path.

```
logging.FileHandler(filename="/home/user/PycharmProjects/project/logs/log_file.log")
```